# How do you set up app with permissions to Azure Compute API

Tags: azure, api, permissions

I am creating an API client for Azure Compute. I want the ability to start/stop/restart my Azure virtual machines.

In the past when I've created apps using the Graph API, I created a new app registration and then gave the app permissions for the actions I wanted under 'Microsoft Graph API' permissions list.

However, I cannot find Azure Compute listed in the available Microsoft APIs. I'm confused as to what I need to do in order to get API permissions for Azure compute as opposed to some of the other APIs.

I've spent the morning searching for tutorials or example implementations to look through, but combinations of Azure/Compute/API/permissions/etc... don't seem to ever come up with the results that I'm looking for.

Has anyone done something like this? Is it possible to use application permissions for Azure compute or is it entirely separate? Will it require a service account instead?

Comment: The UX for this sucks. I also could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I cannot find Azure Compute listed in the available Microsoft
> APIs. I'm confused as to what I need to do in order to get API
> permissions for Azure compute as opposed to some of the other APIs.

The API you're looking for is **Azure Service Management**.

[image]

Once you add this delegated permission, you will be able to perform operations on your Virtual Machines provided your Service Principal is assigned an appropriate role (Virtual Machine Contributor, for example) in an Azure Subscription.

Comment: Thank you very much. Azure is such a behemoth it can be pretty confusing for a newbie at times. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the App an RBAC role as though it were a user that you were giving permission to restart VMs. For example, you could go to the resource group that contains the VM, then go to `Access Control (IAM)` -> `Add Role Assignment` -> Add the app registration to the Contributor role.

Comment: Merely assigning an app role is not sufficient (though it is definitely required). You would need to assign permission to execute an API first (please see my answer).

Comment: That appears to be true only for delegated permissions. I have an application that modifies App Gateway, Load Balancer, and Azure DNS configuration without that API permission.

Comment: ...Hmmm...I have never tried it. Are you including it as part of scopes in your request?

Comment: I'm using `AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal()`. Anything that service principal has RBAC permissions to is accessible via the application.