# Get-AzRoleAssignment throws Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException in Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, exception, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am using runbook in Azure Automation Account. In this runbook, i use "run as account" which has Owner rights on the subscription. When i execute the command `Get-AzRoleAssignment`, i get:

```
    Get-AzRoleAssignment : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown. 
    At line:21 char:16 + $listOfUsers = Get-AzRoleAssignment -verbose + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
 CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzRoleAssignment], CloudException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.GetAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

the Service Principal of "run as account" has below permissions:
[image]

Do you have any idea?

Is it an authorization error? If so, which permissions should i give to the SP?

Comment: Considering `Get-AzRoleAssignment` is for RBAC roles in an Azure Subscription, you will need to give `Azure Service Management` permission. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970160/how-do-you-set-up-app-with-permissions-to-azure-compute-api/66970727#66970727.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: @JoyWang, the issue is resolved after applying the Azure Service Management permission. I thought i have written a comment about it. So Gaurav Mantri's proposition has worked.

Comment: Really? I don't believe the `delegated permission` will work in this case, because when you use this command, it essentially uses [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token, `delegated permission` will not take effect.

Comment: I also have a quick test with the `Azure Service Management` permission, it does not work on my side. Are you sure you didn't give some [azure ad admin roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal?context=/azure/active-directory/roles/context/ugr-context) to the service principal? Except my answer, it will also work.

Comment: Besides the permission in the screenshot and the Azure Service Management permission. We have given nothing. I will also test if your solution works but it will take some time. I will let you know.

Comment: @JoyWang, after some time, Azure Service Management permission didn't work. I have tried your solution and it worked. thanks! Marked it as approved solution your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, when you run the command with some parameters e.g. with `ObjectId`, `Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId xxxxx`, it will call the AAD Graph first to verify the object in your tenant.

To solve the issue, just add the ***Application permission*** `Directory.Read.All` of `Azure Active Directory Graph` to your AD App of the RunAs account.

**Note:** In your screenshot, you added the ***Delegated permission*** `Directory.Read.All`, it will not work, it must be ***Application permission***, check the steps below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After giving the permission, it works fine.

[image]